# Finding conditioned distribution for Cauchy distribution

Tags: probability

> Find $P(-a\le X\le a\mid-2a\le X\le 2a)$ where X is a continuous random variable whose probability density function is similer to cauchy-distribution function and its $F(x)=\frac1 2 +\frac{\arctan(x\backslash a)}{\pi}$ where $a>0$.

I know that for two separate variables the condioned distribution is given by $$f_{X=x}(y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$$. 
Also I know that $P(-a\le X\le a)=\displaystyle\int_{-a}^{a}f_X(x)dx$.
How can I applicate the formulas above in order to solve the quaetion?

Comment: Much simpler: when $A\subseteq B$, $P(A|B)=P(A)/P(B)$.

Comment: I agree but if I mustn't use the rule you mentioned (only these formulas)?

Comment: Computing $P(A\mid B)$ without using the fact that $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$? Sure about that?

Comment: Almost... I'm sure we proved it for discrete variables but I'm not sure we proved it for continuous variables.

Comment: Nothing is continuous and there is no random variables at this stage. You are using this formula for two events A and B with B of positive probability (can you name A and B?). Only then do you use what A and B are, to compute P(A) and P(B).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $F$ is continuous, one has
$$
P(-a\leqslant X\leqslant a\mid-2a\leqslant X\leqslant 2a)=\frac{F(a)-F(-a)}{F(2a)-F(-2a)}.
$$
Assuming furthermore that $X$ is symmetric, that is, that $F(x)+F(-x)=1$, one has
$$
P(-a\leqslant X\leqslant a\mid-2a\leqslant X\leqslant 2a)=\frac{2F(a)-1}{2F(2a)-1}.
$$
In the present case,
$$
P(-a\leqslant X\leqslant a\mid-2a\leqslant X\leqslant 2a)=\frac{\arctan1}{\arctan2}=\frac{\pi}{4\arctan2}.
$$